# React Native Android Direct Denied my Camera Permission

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, permission-denied, react-native-camera

The camera on the emulator is working fine and not working in other application since this emulator is fresh.

This is my code for the ScanScreen. I try to get the camera permission but the console.log directly show camera permission denied.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Francis App Camera Permission',
        message:
          'Francis App needs access to your camera ' +
          'so you can take awesome pictures.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can use the camera');
    } else {
      console.log('Camera permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

const ScanScreen = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.item}>Try permissions</Text>
    <Button title="request permissions" onPress={requestCameraPermission} />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  item: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default ScanScreen;
```

I saw a lot of answer said added permission in the AndroidManifest.xml. I added it also didn't work. My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I try to grant permission from the setting but it does not show any permission in the setting.

[The setting page for my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN2Ts.png)

Hope anyone can help me fix this issue. I already find the solutions for 1 week.

Comment: Can you please check this link if it helps https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-react-native-camera

Comment: @inkredusk I followed the installation but it still direct denied the permission